# Ruby Sinatra Unable to get while loop to function correctly

Tags: ruby, loops, sinatra, display

Trying to get this to display different pages based on condition. When positioned inside of the while loop, erb :game only displays an empty page, it displays properly outside of the while loop, but once you enter in a value in the form, it automatically resets the number to 0. What am I missing here?

```
get "/" do 
      count = 5  
      number = params["number"].to_i 

        if number == 0 
         erb :index
        else
          letters = find(number)
          while count > 0 do 

            guess = params["guess"]
            if letters.include?guess
              correct = check_guess(guess, letters)
            else
              count -= 1
            end
            disp = display(letters, correct)  
            erb :game, :locals => {:letters => letters, :disp => disp}   
          end

       end
end
```

Comment: Instead of `while count > 0 do` , you can also use `5.times do ` and get rid of `count` variable as it will not be needed in that case.  For `erb` issue, refer to the answer posted by other user.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing `erb` line inside loop. It won't work. Actually it doesn't make sense. View will only be presented after the whole loop is done. As a result when view is rendering, by that time, value of `count` is `0`.

You cannot render multiple view in an action! You'll have to calculate and then finally render your template.

Comment: so how would i go about that? set up a different action? ie post "/" do ... end?